# Google street view Image API resolution

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there any information of how many pixels per meter in Google streetview image API? I see only fov- field of view, and heading for angle, but there is no resolution information.

Answer (score 1):

The standard free plan offers image of `640 x 640` maximum, but if you are premium user, you can get maximum of `2048 x 2048` resolution.

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits

Comment: It seems premium accounts are no longer available. https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview Do you know if it is still possible to get 2048 by 2048 resolution?

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down to [Image Size,](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/index) it say Street View images can be returned in any size up to 640 by 640 pixels.

Comment: That is the image resolution. I want to know the real life resolution, i.e. how many pixels are in one meter.